$.get(code_url) executes code returned, without using eval( ) neither appending it to DOM. jQuery security fail?
I was debugging my NodeJS app when I came to this huge fact : Using jQuery, a simple
$.get(code_url)

Where code_url is an URL toward javascript code on the server, does executes the code.
What is expected is :
$.get("script.js", function(data) {
    // data contains the content of 'script.js' as a string
    // We can choose either to :
    // - Append it to the DOM
    // - Evaluate it using eval()
    // - Store it for later use
});

But still, even with nothing done in the callback, code is indeed executed.
I tried to recreate a server almost empty, with just a few lines of code to make sure that it does not come from my project. Even with a total of a dozen of lines, I can reproduce.
NodeJS server :
const express = require('express');
const App = express();
App.use(express.static('www'));
App.listen(5000);

index.js (executed by the index.html)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("utils.js")
});

utils.js (served as static in www/ by the server)
console.log("Hello World");
let a=1000;
console.log(Math.PI*a);

And BOOM, code executed :

NB: Issue seems to happen only on local server, but still I think it's quite a serious issue. I just cannot manage to download any piece of code without having it executed on the fly... Come on. Did I find a HUGE jQuery bug ?
Tested on

jQuery 3.6.3 and 3.7.1
Google Chrome (Version 123.0.6312.122 (Official Build) (64-bit))
Linux Ubuntu 22.04


Working as intended.

I've not tried, but you might try adding a 3rd parameter "text/plain" after the success callback function. I'm not sure whether that overrides the MIME type that comes back from the server.

Pointy, Can you precise a little bit please :) ? If it's the intended behavior, then how should I download a JS file when I just want to retrieve its content without executing it ? [EDIT] just saw previous answer

I tried with the "text" or "text/plain" as 3rd param, indeed it prevents from execution. Thanks ! :)

The server must be returning the Content-type: text/javascript header.
If you don't specify the dataType argument to $.get(), jQuery infers the type from the Content-Type header. text/javascript corresponds to dataType = "script". And from the documentation:

"script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.

In other words, $.get("script.js") is effectively equivalent to $.getScript("script.js")
If you want to retrieve the source code without evaluation, specify the text dataType explicitly:
$.get("script.js", "text");


Answer given by @Pointy :
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("utils.js", function(data){
        
    }, "text/plain")
});

Prevents the code from being executed
